# Why text content shows in hidden div

Tags: jquery, css, html

I tried to hide a overlapping `<div>` but the text inside this `<div>` shows anyway.
I'm using JQUERY to hide the `<div>` like this... `$('#divinfo').css(display,"none");`
this is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#divfoto').addClass('clasefoto');
        $('#divinfo').addClass('claseinfo');
        $('#divinfo').css(display,"none");

        onClick();

    });
```

the html code...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="divfoto">
                <p>WORD1</p>
                <div id="divinfo" >
                    <p>WORD2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and this is the css code...

```
.clasefoto{

background-color:#0000FF;
position: relative;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
border:5px solid #FF00FF;
```

}

```
.claseinfo{
background-color: #FFFF00;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 0%;
```

}

and the image, please help me!
[image]

Comment: You missed the quotes, `"`: `$('#divinfo').css("display","none");`

Comment: you could also use `$('#divinfo').hide();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing quotes on your jquery css():

```
$('#divinfo').css("display","none");
```

However, it will be better practice to first set the display:none in CSS and not jQuery.

`#divinfo {display:none;}` will render quicker on the screen than $`('#divinfo').css('display','none');`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('#divinfo').hide();
```

instead of

```
$('#divinfo').css(display,"none");
```